# Is there a way to have 'master file' for storybook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader, storybook

I've been wondering if there **is a way to have a single 'master' file for storybook?**

> Here's how I imagine the file hierarchy looking:
>
> ```
> •
> └── stories
>     └── button
>         ├── Button.js
>         └── Button.stories.js
>     └── SearchBox
>         └──  SearchBox.js
>         └──  SearchBox.story.js
>     index.stories.js
> ```
>
> Where the `index.stories.js` would contain imports of all the other
>   stories.

---

### `Button.stories.js`

```
import React from 'react''

export const withText = () => <Button>Hello Button</Button>;

export const withEmoji = () => (
  <Button>
    <span role="img" aria-label="so cool">
         
    </span>
  </Button>
);

export default { title: 'Button' };
```

Now this would work if I pasted the code into `index.stories.js` but I just want to import the separate stories into the master file and I can't wrap my head around how. I tried following to no avail:

### `index.stories.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from './button/Button.stories'

export const Main = <Button/>
export default = { title: 'Main-Testing' }
```

This however doesn't work and just results in `babel-loader` parsing errors. Also it feels incorrect to be importing a `React.Component` when I should be importing a story here.

---

> *PS: I know I could simpy import all the story files individually in `preview.js` or `main.js` but I was thinking about solution specific
>   for having one 'master' file.*

So, how should this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting each story variation as a named export from it's own story file, and then import each of them into index.stories.js, and export them all together again from there.

For example:

index.stories.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { First, Second } from './components/component.stories.js';
// First and Second are named exports from their own stories

export default {
  title: 'Show All Stories Here'
}

const AllComponents = () => <div><First /><Second /></div>

export  {First, Second, AllComponents}; 
// export all components individually, and then export them all together
```

Your resulting structure in storybook UI would be:

```
- Show All Stories Here
   - First // First would be displayed here
   - Second // Second would be displayed here
   - Allstuff // both First and Second would be displayed here
```